# Change the color of "a" tag inside of "li"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried to do it by css, using:

```
#mainmenu ul li:hover a
{
  color: #000000;
}
```

But it is not working, then i tried using jQuery, with:

```
function change()
{
  $(this).find('a').css('color','#000000');
}
```

Calling onMouseOver inside the `<li>`, but it is also not working...

Any idea?

Comment: Try with `color: black !important` and if it works then look for the style overriding it and re-organize your code

Comment: Ok @JMCCreative, didn't know about that, but i always vote for the answers.

Comment: @Ramon, glad to help, but you still haven't done it! Please start today! Mark the answer below "accepted"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `color: black !important` and if it works then look for the style overriding it and re-organize your code.

Comment: I was just writing a comment: " don't you wish you put that in an answer!"

Comment: That awkward moment when the same comment gets more upvote xD

Answer (score 0):

The CSS code posted works when tested with the simplest possible HTML like

```
<div id=mainmenu>
<ul><li><a href=foo>link</ul>
</div>
```

and with no other style sheet used. This means that in your real page, there is either some error in HTML syntax or, more probably, some other style sheet rule that overrides this rule.

Thus, you should analyze and modify the style sheets. If you need further help, you should post minimal code that still exhibits the problem.

Using `!important` can be useful in making sure that it’s not an HTML problem or typo in CSS code, but `!important` should rarely be used on live pages, especially in cases where you don’t really know how your style sheets work together.

Answer (score 0):

Just try hovering

```
#mainmenu ul li a:hover
{
  color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS can handle your problem anyway if you want to solve using jquery you can use this link [Jquery Hyperlink Plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-hyperlink-plugins/)